# What other prerequisites are necessary to run my service worker as a service on a Windows Server virtual machine that utilizes the Selenium webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, windows-services

I have developed a service worker using .NET 7, and it successfully runs when tested through dotnet build. However, when attempting to publish the code and run it as a Windows service in the background, I consistently encounter Error 1053. I am utilizing Selenium webdriver to extract data, and I have installed the latest drivers and Chrome on the server. Despite this, I continue to receive Error 1053 and require assistance in deploying the service. I am unsure of what I am missing or what mistake I may be making.

[image: Error message]

**Is it possible that the server is not recognizing the driver, resulting in a timeout during startup?**

The nuget packages i am using are the following:

````
RUN dotnet add package Selenium.Support --version 4.8.1
RUN dotnet add package Azure.Storage.Blobs --version 12.15.1
RUN dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions --version 1.1.0
RUN dotnet add package Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions --version 4.1.1
RUN dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets --version 1.17.2
RUN dotnet add package System.Threading.AccessControl --version 7.0.1

Other installations
Latest stabel chromedriver - https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/
Chrome web browser```
````

Code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/dAjhfK0i

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Screenshot_WorkerService.Interface;
using Screenshot_WorkerService.Service;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Extensions;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Screenshot_WorkerService
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
        private readonly IBlobStorageServiceClient _blobServiceClient;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IBlobStorageServiceClient blobServiceClient)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _blobServiceClient = blobServiceClient;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTime.Now);
                var timeout = 10;

                _logger.LogInformation("Reading urls values from blob");
                var urlConfiguration = await _blobServiceClient.DownloadConfigrationBlob();

                if (urlConfiguration.Urls is not null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in urlConfiguration.Urls)
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation("Preparing headless web browser");
                        var options = new ChromeOptions();
                        options.AddArguments(new List<string> { "--headless", "--hide-scrollbars" });

                        using var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
                        _logger.LogInformation("web browser complete");
                        driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(item.Width, item.Height);
                        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(item.Url);
                        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout);

                        try
                        {
                            _logger.LogInformation($"Searching class element: {timeout}");
                            var element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout)).Until((d) =>
                            {
                                d.Navigate().GoToUrl(item.Url);
                                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                                return d.FindElement(By.ClassName("v-menu"));
                            });

                            var screenshot = driver.TakeScreenshot();
#if DEBUG
                            screenshot.SaveAsFile($"{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}.png");
#endif
                            //Save to blobStorage
                            _blobServiceClient.UploadImageToBlobAsync(screenshot);

                        }
                        catch (NoSuchElementException e)
                        {
                            // try Login
                            _logger.LogInformation($"Exception: {e.Message}");
                            _logger.LogInformation($"Trying automate login");

                            var username = driver.FindElement(By.Id("input-12\""));
                            username.Clear();
                            username.SendKeys("");

                            var password = driver.FindElement(By.Id("input-13"));
                            password.Clear();
                            password.SendKeys("");

                            var loginButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='v-btn v-btn--block v-btn--outlined theme--dark v-size--default primary--text']\r\n"));
                            loginButton.Click();

                            driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout);

                            var screenshot = driver.TakeScreenshot();

#if DEBUG
                            screenshot.SaveAsFile($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss")}.png");
#endif
                            //Save to blobStorage
                            _blobServiceClient.UploadImageToBlobAsync(screenshot);
                        }
                        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException e)
                        {
                            _logger.LogInformation($"Exception trying login was timed out: {e.Message}");
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            _logger.LogInformation($"Exception: {e.Message}");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("Reading returned no urls, check the blobstorage for url values");
                }
                _logger.LogWarning("Done!");
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20), stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There should be an event for this, have you checked the event viewer? Also, do you have logging in the service?

Comment: What account is the service running as?

Comment: Ok I see now you have logging (I edited the code into your question).. anything in the logs at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that this is the problem but `ExecuteAsync` should perfrom await as soon as possible, so the execution control is returned to the caller as soon as possible, current implementation will block until first iteration of outer loop is finished. Try one of the following:

```cs
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    await Task.Yield();
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // ...
        }
    });
}
```

P.S.

Do not forget to install and configure the hosting to use [`WindowsServices`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices/).

Answer (score 1):

I got this running by double checking the documentation from Microsoft - [Create Windows Service using BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service).

I learned that I needed to add nuget package [`Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices/) and add the following to the Program.cs

```
services.AddWindowsService(options =>
{
    options.ServiceName = "ServiceName";
});
```